# How to extract last characters of type number javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, numbers, character

I have some strings like:

row_row1_1, 
row_row1_2, 
row_row1_13, 
row_row1_287, 
...

and I want to take the last numbers of that strings, ut can be 1, 2, 13 or 287. That strings are generated automatically and I can't control if there is going to be 1 number, 2 numbers, 3 numbers...

I would like to make a function that takes the last number character, or the numbers after the second '_' character. is there any idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are we talking an _Array of Strings_ or a _String_ with `,` delimiters? (In either case though, you'll probably find it easiest to use a _RegExp_, `\d+$` or `\d+,`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your strings always follow this pattern str_str_str then you can use the `split` method and get the 2º index of the array, like this:

```
var number = str.split('_')[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

As @PaulS said, you can always use *regex* for that purpose:

```
var getLastNumbers = function(str)
{
    return str.replace(/.+(_)/, '');
};

getLastNumbers("row_row1_287"); // Will result -> 287
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozru4qsp/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

**Taking the last numeric characters**

```
function getNumericSuffix(myString) {
    var reversedString = myString.split('').reverse().join('');
    var i, result="";
    for(i = 0; i < reversedString.length; i++) {
        if(!isNaN(reversedString[i])) {
            result = reversedString[i] + result;
        } else break;
    }
    return parseInt(result); // assuming all number are integers
}
```